# Collapse hyperlink when Command.CanExecute returns false

Tags: wpf, xaml

Simple question is: how do I hide a hyperlink when its bound command .CanExecute returns false?

The xaml:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding IncludesCanExecuteCommand}">Link text</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

The code:

```
...
private ICommand _includesCanExecuteCommand;
....
    _includesCanExecuteCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteTheCommand, CanExecuteTheCommand);
....

public ICommand IncludesCanExecuteCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _includesCanExecuteCommand;
    }
}

....

public bool CanExecuteTheCommand()
{
    return BooleanResult();
}

public void ExecuteTheCommand()
{
    DoSomeWork();
}
```

How do I style the Textblock/Hyperlink(or Run if needed) such that the link collapses when the CanExecute() function returns false?  I've tried:

```
<Hyperlink.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultHyperlinkStyle}">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
 </Hyperlink.Style>
```

I've also tried putting the style on the textblock (can't get at the hyperlink) and in a Run inside the hyperlink (no visibility property).

All ideas gratefully received!

Answer (score 3):

I spent a lot of time looking at this today and nothing worked until I tried this.
Basically the solution is to put the text inside the Hyperlink in a textblock and then set that's visibility using a BooleanToVisiblityConverter as the inner TextBlock becomes disabled when the hyperlink becomes disabled.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:BooleanToVisibiltyConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibiltyConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<TextBlock >
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding EditDetailsCommand}">
        <TextBlock
            Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEnabled
                , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}
                , Mode=OneWay
                , Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibiltyConverter}}">
        Edit Details 
        </TextBlock>
    </Hyperlink>                  
</TextBlock >


public class BooleanToVisibiltyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value"); 

        if (!(value is bool))
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected type of value must be boolean");

        if (parameter != null && !(parameter is Visibility))
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected type of parameter must be Visibility");

        Visibility falseVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        if (parameter != null)
        {
            falseVisibility = (Visibility)parameter;

            if (falseVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Cannot pass visible to expected false value parameter.");
            }
        }

        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : falseVisibility;  
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value"); 

        if (!(value is Visibility))
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected type of value must be Visibility");

        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value"); 
        }

        Visibility v = (Visibility)value;

        return v == Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution.

Answer (score 0):

So there seems to be two problems here..

I would probably be tempted to set a property after calling
    IncludesCanExecuteCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged() 
which will cause the command to reevaluate its CanExecuteCommand..

Put the hyperlink in a panel and then bind the visibility to the property in 1.) with a converter to return a valid Visiblility enum such as Collapsed, Visible etc.

So for clarity - something like

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsHyperlinkVisible, Mode=TwoWay,     Converter=boolToVisibilityConverter}">
  <TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding WhateverTheHyperlinkDoesCommand}">Link text</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

And the viewmodel looks something like this (if the viewmodelbase implements some version of NotifyPropertyChanged...

```
 public class ViewModel : NotificationViewModelBase 
 {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            this.WhateverTheHyperlinkDoesCommand =
                new DelegateCommand<object>(
                    this.ExecuteWhateverTheHyperlinkDoesCommand, this.CanWhateverTheHyperlinkDoesCommand);
        }

        private void ExecuteWhateverTheHyperlinkDoesCommand(object arg)
        {
            this.SomeOtherProperty = true;            }

        private bool someOtherProperty;

        public bool SomeOtherProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return this.someOtherProperty;
            }

            set
            {
                if (this.ChangeAndRaisePropertyChanged(
                    () => this.SomeOtherProperty, value, ref this.someOtherProperty))
                {
                    this.WhateverTheHyperlinkDoesCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                }
            }
        }

            private bool isHyperlinkProperty;

        public bool IsHyperlinkProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isHyperlinkProperty;
            }

            set
            {
                this.ChangeAndRaisePropertyChanged(() => this.IsHyperlinkProperty, value, ref this.isHyperlinkProperty);
            }
        }

        private bool CanWhateverTheHyperlinkDoesCommand(object obj)
        {
            // So based on a certain condition - lets say some other property

            if (this.SomeOtherProperty == false)
            {
                this.IsHyperlinkProperty = true;
                return false;
            }

            this.IsHyperlinkProperty = false;
            return true;
        }

        public DelegateCommand<object> WhateverTheHyperlinkDoesCommand { get; set; }
```

}
}

Comment: Not sure I understand your temptation, can you explain in code maybe?

Comment: Yes, I see.  That seems like a lot of code that I was trying to ask whether I could avoid because the hyperlink already knows whether or not it can execute.  Thanks for the clear notes though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no attached property of TextBlock.Visibility on a Hyperlink. Place the style directly in the containing TextBlock of the Hyperlink and that should resolve the Visibility.

If not, then create a [bool to visibility converter](https://www.google.com/search?q=bool%20to%20visibility%20converter%20wpf) and set the converter on the TextBlock for the Visibility; and bind the converter to the CanExecuteTheCommand property.

It should be noted that if the Property Changed notification isn't raised on the CanExecuteTheCommand property, then the converter will only evaluate the first time the view is loaded; after that, it will become stale.

Comment: Couple of things to note here: 1. The style can't bind to the hyperlink's IsEnabled, which is I think what you're getting at; 2. Binding to another property that the Can.. method also uses feels like a fudge because something's already doing that job, but thanks for the offers.

Comment: Binding the property multiple times is not a 'fudge'; it's standard practice. You need to use a bool to visibility converter and bind to whatever property determines if the link is available or not; regardless if that property is bound to something else as well.

Comment: I understand, the "fudge" feel though is because I'm adding code in order to essentially style the hyperlink according to one of its properties.  However, thanks for clarifying - the simple answer to the simple part of the question is "you can't - do it yourself" :)

Answer (score 0):

Naming the hyperlink works too and gives you some flexibility. Also, you can use the built in `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverterx:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEnabled,
                                ElementName=Linky,
                                Mode=OneWay,
                                Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">>
    <Hyperlink x:Name="Linky" Command="{Binding EditDetailsCommand}">
        <Run Text="Edit Details"/>
    </Hyperlink>                  
</TextBlock >
```